# how to get Dojox charting working within MyEclipse for Spring

Tags: myeclipse, dojox.charting

I want to display a chart - am using [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/).

These

```
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.Claro.js");</script>
```

show in the chrome developers view as

> Uncaught Error: Could not load 'dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D.js'; last tried '../dojox/charting/widget/Chart2D/js.js'

What is the method for including and using dojox functions when you are in MyEclipse 4 Spring??

Google has suggested updating Spring-JS to the latest version (as the ME4S version is old and the Spring-JS does not include dojox), and also including the Jojo librabry in the web app root dir so the resource servelet will find it. Tried these and every other combination to no avail.

I have had no problem with getting Jojo TabContainer working. It uses this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");</script>
```

Also, do all beginners take this long to get up to speed?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the files incorrectly; notice that you're using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D.js");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.Claro.js");</script>
```

when it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Chart2D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.Claro");</script>
```

Basically, drop the '.js' off from the dojo.require.